# QPushButton is focused when switch stack in QStackWidget

Tags: pyqt5

## Question

I creadte a `demo.py` as follow to describle my question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGradient
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QListWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QStackedWidget, QWidget, QApplication


class M(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set()

    def set(self):
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.central_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        #
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        #
        self.first_button = QPushButton('first stack')
        self.second_button = QPushButton('second stack')
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.first_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.second_button, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.stack_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.stack_widget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        # add sub widget for stackwidget
        self.add_sub_widget_for_stack()
        # add func for button
        self.first_button.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked, x=0: self.switch_stack(x)
        )
        self.second_button.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked, x=1: self.switch_stack(x)
        )

    def add_sub_widget_for_stack(self):
        print('add')
        # add first sub widget
        self.first_sub_widget = QWidget()
        self.first_sub_widget.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        button_1 = QPushButton('First')
        button_2 = QPushButton('Second')
        self.first_sub_widget.layout().addWidget(button_1)
        self.first_sub_widget.layout().addWidget(button_2)
        self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.first_sub_widget)
        # add second sub widget
        self.second_sub_widget = QWidget()
        self.second_sub_widget.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        list_ = QListWidget()
        self.second_sub_widget.layout().addWidget(list_)
        self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.second_sub_widget)

    def switch_stack(self, index_):
        self.stack_widget.setCurrentIndex(index_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = M()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I pressed `second stack` go into the second stack and press mouse on the QListWidget, then when i press `first stack` go back to the first stack, the `First` button will be checked and can't be cancel.

### Others

Picture for demo, maybe the `button_1` with value of `first` is not checkable, but its border is blue after the operation above.
[image]

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` ... `button1.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)` (and again for button2). The last phrase of your question is not clear.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, it's useful, and the last pharse of my question is mean I want take a screenshot for this question, but I when I do this, the qt ui will lose focus, and `button_1` is not checked.

Comment: @musicamante And I would like to ask you why this happens

Comment: Those buttons are not checkable, so your question is unclear.

Comment: The current demo script does not show any of the behaviour you describe. Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I modified my question

Comment: @ekhumoro I modified my question.

Comment: @zhoualias That is not a *checked* button, it's a **focused** one. That said, it's unclear what you really want to achieve, so please try to explain yourself better. If you have problems with English language, try to find somebody that could help you, but always remember that technical terms are **extremely** important: you cannot confuse the "focus" and "checked" states, as they are two very different and unrelated things.

Comment: @musicamante I'm sorry for the wrong description, I just want to know why the `button_1` is be focused after the opearation above.

Comment: @zhoualias Because you clicked it. If you properly did what suggested at the beginning (`button1.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)`) at the right moment (usually, just after the creation of the widget), that wouldn't happen. That said, your whole structure is very confusing: I'm under the impression that you want to add buttons that, when clicked, switch the widget of the QStackedWidget; if that's the case, calling `self.stack_widget.addWidget` makes absolutely ***no*** sense: by doing that, you'll add the buttons for the "first" page, and the list widget to the *second* page (which is never shown).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, I will modify my UI code structure.